# What is the time and space complexity of the count string function

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def count(substring, string):
    """
    >>> count("bc","abcabcabc")
    3
    """
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(string) - len(substring) + 1):
        counter += string.startswith(substring, i)

    return counter
```

This is a function to count the number of recurrence of a substring in the base string. I think the time complexity is O(n) since I only iterate the string once. I think the space complexity is O(n) as well because I increment the counter in the loop N times. Can someone tell me if I am right or wrong?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity is O(nm) where n=len(s) and m=len(t) for the reason you provide, but incrementing `counter` doesn't cause it take up more space, so the space complexity of this function is O(1). No matter how long the input string is, you still only store a single variable, `count`.

[Edited to correct egregious error pointed out by poster]

Comment: I think for the time complexity it should be O(n*m) given a string s length n and a substring t length m, because the startwith function also will check m times.

Comment: That is correct, I didn't pay close enough attention!

Comment: no worries haha, btw do you think there is a way to improve the performance, like speed up to O(n)?

Comment: I don't myself but the CPython [count implementation](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) seems like it should be faster, as should the various algorithms it relies on. The basic trick it does is preprocess the `t` string to generate a vector (or two) that tell you how far you can safely skip ahead in `s` when you encounter a mismatch at a given index in `t`.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h) is the source code.